# Implementing Observer pattern C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, android-ndk, subject

I'm working on a C++ project in Android. What I want to achieve is make an async call in C++, then send the data back over JNI. It's a simple proof of concept, but that also means my C++ knownledge is limited.

I've got all the functionalities working, but wanting to make the C++ side of the project "better" I want to implement an Observer Pattern.
I used this as tutorial: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/328365/Understanding-and-Implementing-Observer-Pattern-in

After adding everything (ofc modified to my project) I'm getting the following compile error: 
template argument 2 is invalid in the ASubject.h at the line:

```
std::vector<PoCCplusplus*> list;
```

Subject h and cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include "PoCCplusplus.h"


class ASubject
{
    //Lets keep a track of all the shops we have observing
    std::vector<PoCCplusplus*> list;

public:
    void Attach(PoCCplusplus *cws);
    void Detach(PoCCplusplus *cws);
    void Notify(char *xml);
};

#include "ASubject.h"

using namespace std;

void ASubject::Attach(PoCCplusplus *cws)
{
    list.push_back(cws);
}
void ASubject::Detach(PoCCplusplus *cws)
{
    list.erase(std::remove(list.begin(), list.end(), cws), list.end());
}

void ASubject::Notify(char *xml)
{
    for(vector<PoCCplusplus*>::const_iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if(*iter != 0)
        {
            (*iter)->Update(xml);
        }
    }
}
```

It's probably something really simple I'm missing, but I just cant find the solution for it.

Comment: What do you define in "ASubject.h"? Is it the implementation of ASubject? Also, you name the attribute "list" in `ASubject` - did you by any chance use `using namespace std` somewhere, this could cause a rpoblem for an attribute named `list`. Edit: yes, you have `using namespace std` above the definitions of member functions, and you are using a variable named `list` all over, with `list` being introduced from `std` by `#include<list>`.

Comment: you have a conflict with std::list and list for sure, plus it isn't a list, it a vector :P

Comment: So if I get it right, by using namespace std which include <list> already. I got it defined multiple times? But wouldn't that throw a "multiple reference" error?
And yeah it's a vector gotta change that ;)

Comment: @Tristan, you don't define the list container twice, you introduce two names in the local scope - one name for the attribute `list` and another name for the type `std::list<Type, Allocator<Type>>`. Its allways good to avoid naming attributes in this way, make the name more descriptive, as your comment states - its a list of observed shops : `observedShops`.

Comment: Ah the problem was indeed the bad name in list, and I had a circular dependency going on...
So after cleaning up that, changing the name into something more specific. Its solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Rename the `list` attribute in `ASubject` to something else , say `observedShops` (as named in your comment already).
- Avoid `using namespace std` in library code.

Answer (score 1):

You

`#include <list>`

so 'list' is already a defined type.  Choose a different variable name.

This is why it's a good idea to not use:

```
using namespace std;
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, observer can be done shorter, if you use boost::signals2:

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::signals2::signal;
using boost::bind;

struct Some {
    void Update(char* xml) {
        cout << "Update\n";
    }
    void operator()(char* xml) {
        cout << "operator\n";
    }
};

void func(char* xml) {
    cout << "func\n";
}

int main() {
    signal<void(char*)> s;
    Some some;
    Some other;
    s.connect(some);
    s.connect(bind(&Some::Update, other, _1));
    s.connect(func);
    char str[10] = "some str";
    s(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But I believe boost library isn't standard in the ndk.

Comment: @Tristan Well, yes, but boost::signals2 is header only, so it's not hard to add it to project.